# Vectorize 3d operation in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

Can you vectorize a operation where the columns of U are added to cwx and the result is stored in a 3d array?

A non-vectorized solution:

```
cwx =rand([500,100]);
U = rand([500 10]);

F = zeros([500 100 10]);
for y = 1:10
    F(:,:,y) = bsxfun(@plus,U(:,y),cwx);
end
```

Comment: In your non-vectorized solution the variable n_clases is not defined.

Comment: `magic` uses only one scalar input, `magic([500,100]);` does the same as `magic(500);`.

Comment: Yes. I changed the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a single call to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), provided you first [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the second and third dimensions of `U`:

```
F = bsxfun(@plus, permute(U, [1 3 2]), cwx);
```